# Simplifying $(3/2)^i$ for $i = 0$ to $\\(log_2 n) -1$

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\\(log_2 n)-1} \frac{3^i}{2^i}$$

I have been working on solving a recurrence, and finally simplified to this step. However, I am lost as to where to proceed now. I know the sum of powers of 2, but I don't know what to do since it's in the denominator.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know the sum of powers of $\dfrac3 2$?

Comment: What is lgn - 1 in the title?

Comment: Have I edited the title appropriately? Please change it if not, Ardvark.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner no I don't, isn't that just the answer? How do you find the sum of powers of a fraction

Comment: that's the answer; do you know how to sum powers of $5$?  $a$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint $$\sum_{i=0}^{N}r^i=\frac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r}$$ when $r\ne 1$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2 n} \frac{3^i}{2^i}=\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2 n} \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^i.$$

Now use the [formula for the sum of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series).